Asian martial arts movie with two brothers
Basic story: I remember seeing this movie in the early 2000's. There are these two brothers training in a temple until their master lets them go to the city. Once they get to the city they try to make some money with bets and catch the attention of guards. 
Later the brothers argue and fight each other to the death.
Some other scenes: In the temple while cleaning, they swing a wet towel at each other, which is shown later when they fight when they use swords on each other.
Also in the temple, while sitting on a table they fight each other with kicks and then break the table.

Sounds like Tai Chi Master from 1993 with Jet Li. From Wiki:

Junbao and Tienbo grow up together in a Shaolin Temple as monks, studying the martial arts and generally getting into trouble. They are both expelled from the temple after Tienbo almost kills a fellow student who cheats in a fight against him. Aided in their escape by their sympathetic teacher, they receive final instructions regarding the potential paths of their different personalities, with a specific warning given to Tienbo. They both then go into the outside world to find their way in life.

While at the temple, they fight each other with wet towels and also kick-fight while sitting at a table (which they break). They end up as enemies and fight to the death in the end. I think they're just childhood friends, though, not brothers. Here's the trailer on Youtube; The entire movie is also currently available and you can see the table scene around 8:45 and the towel scene around 9:45.
